# Payment Gateways - How to pay to sellers/vendors

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment

I would like to start a site where people can sell items for others to buy. As the website owner I would take a cut (say 20%) and the seller receive the remainder. I'm guessing this is a similar model to themeforest.net.

Taking payments from buyers would presumably be as with a standard eCommerce site but my question is what is the best way to handle payments to sellers and how would I automate the payment of the sellers fees? Which payment gateways offer this feature?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished as a chained payment using PayPal Adaptive Payments. Have a look at the product overview here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

The following page will contain or link to everything you need to get started: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/

Comment: Hi PP_MSI_KevinG, I'll check it out. Looks like it could be what i'm looking for. Would they need a PayPal account to receive the money or could it pay it direct into their bank? Thanks

Comment: From the documentation: The application owner must have a PayPal Business account. Senders and receivers can have any PayPal account type. Senders and receivers are not required to have PayPal accounts initially. PayPal prompts a sender to create an account before a payment can be completed. A receiver must create an account to receive the funds after the payment completes.